# Unreliable algorithm for determine if points lie along a line?

Tags: 3d

So lets say I have some points $A,B,C$.

A method I have been shown for determining if the lie along a straight line is thus:

$\mathrm{If}\space|AC|=|AB|+|BC| \space\mathrm{then\space A,B\space and\space C\space lie\space on\space a\space straight\space line. }$

However, this doesn't seem like a very reliable method to me.  It seems like a situation such as this would create a false positive.
[image]

If this is not the case, how do you prove that $|AB|+|BC|\neq|AC|$ in all cases if they points are *not* on a straight line?

If this case will indeed cause the algorithm to fail, what reliable algorithm can I use?

Thanks...

***EDIT:***: Whenever I built a triangle that would cause this algorithm to fail, (ie, a=10,b=5,c=5 and others) I get $cos{C}=1$, implying a straight, line?  How can one *prove* this is always the case?

Comment: Why should the equality hold in the second example ?

Comment: It's a poorly drawn image, I know.  But, can the points form a triangle where one arm is twice as long as the other, thus an arbitrarily chosen point A could possibly be twice as far away from point C as it is from point B, thus,$|AB|+|BC|=|AC|+2|AB|=2|BC|$

Comment: Colinearity is usually checked using cross product. You might find [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html) useful.

Comment: But the claim |AB| + |BC| = |AC| does not hold, if A,B and C form a triangle.

Comment: I've tried to construct several such triangles and they always end up with a 0 degree angle!  But how can I prove this is ALWAYS the case?

Answer (score 1):

The equality $|AB| + |BC| = |AC|$ holds if and only if point $B$ lies on the segment $AC$.

Still, this is a bad basis for a practical algorithm. If you implement this, you'll have to calculate three square roots, which is slow. Not to mention that this just looks bad.

A good way to determine whether or not points $A$, $B$ and $C$ are collinear is purely linear. It goes like this.

Calculate coordinates of vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$: $\vec{AB} = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $\vec{AC} = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$. Now, points $A$, $B$ and $C$ are collinear if and only if all the equalities below are true:
$$
\begin{align*}
x_1 y_2 &= x_2 y_1 \\
y_1 z_2 &= y_2 z_1 \\
z_1 x_2 &= z_2 x_1
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: In other words, if their cross-product is 0.

Answer (score 0):

A little extension makes the algorithm work :

Consider $|AB|$ , $|AC|$ and $|BC|$. Then, C is on the line AB , if and only if the
 greatest of the three numbers is the sum of the others. In Particular, if C = A
 or C = B, then C is trivially always on the line AB.